# Creating a map route on iOS app with several points

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit, mapkit

I am using Objective C for the first time and instead of choosing to do a nice simple app I'm trying to make a tour application which will have the route mapped on it with the tourist points marked. I eventually want to add audio to the points but for now just want the route mapped and working!

Yes I know I'm silly for picking such a hard task - but any help? I am just stuck on how to get into this. I don't want anything fancy, I really just want to get the map up with the points and route displayed.

Comment: If you are new to iOS and Objective-C then I recommend you do one (or both) of the following first: `1)` Visit http://www.raywenderlich.com and work through some of the tutorials or `2)` The best option is to open iTunesU (in iTunes on the Mac or in the app on an iDevice) and download and follow the Stanford iOS course `Developing iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad`.  These will get you started with the fun of app building and when you have a specific problem you can't fix then come back and post a specific question. Enjoy !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store specific points on a plist file (or a common text file).

Once you have those points, u have to make a mapview on your app (just drag)
and then, read the points, and add a mark to the map.

You can also draw lines between those points, so u can display the route.

Apple´s mapview and gps, has a method that allows u to know when the phone
has moved. When u detect that, u can check if the phone is near of one of
the audio points, and then start to play the sound. (there is a function
that gives you the distance between 2 points of the map).